# How do I ask a question distinguishing between "X" and "Y"?

Tags: questions

I am not sure how to ask questions to find differences between two matters or distinguish them from each other with many similarities that they have as much as many differences. For example:

> I want to find how to recognize "X" of "Y".

These questions come in my mind:

1. How can you recognize/distinguish "X" of "Y"?
2. How can you recognize/distinguish "X" and "Y"?
3. How can you recognize/distinguish "X" from "Y"?
4. What differences/similarities "X" and "Y" have?
5. Which differences/similarities "X" and "Y" have?

Comment: Maybe your question wants to ask "How can one **distinguish** depression {and / from} sadness?" or "How are depression and sadness similar and different?" They aren't the same thing. Sadness is something that everyone feels sometime or other: it's normal, not pathological. Depression is similar to sadness in some ways, but depression (both _topical_ & _clinical_ depression) is pathological. None of your sentences works. Please rethink your question.

Comment: Forget the matter of context. I edited it to be able focus on the question.

Comment: Interested in how you define matters here. Matter x could be recognised as a case of 'a' with matter y defined as not being so. In seeking to recognise or distinguish between two matters having as many similarities as differences you would probably end up trying to identify a generalised characteristics for each by which to differentiate them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to guess OP's context is that he has something he knows is either an **X** or a **Y**, and he wants to ask how to determine *which of the two possibilities* it is. That question could be phrased as...

> *"How can you **distinguish** X **from** Y?"*

Minor variations include using ***do*** instead of ***can***, and ***I/we*** instead of ***you***.
Less commonly, perhaps, ***differentiate***, and/or *X **and** Y*.

Probably more common in speech (certainly more informal)...

> *"How can you **tell** X **from** Y?"*
>    *"How can we **tell** X **and** Y **apart**?"*
>   *"How can I **tell** them **apart**?"*

Comment: A more formal way to request this might be: _Compare and contrast X and Y_. The phrase **compare and contrast** is often used as a request to analyze the similarities and differences between two things, particularly in academic settings (students are often asked write compare-and-contrast essays, for example).

Comment: @J.R.: Yes, that's certainly a common way of asking students to list significant differences. Which *might* be OP's intended context (but we don't know because we haven't been given the exact context). I guess it's a matter of whether you want to ***list/discuss all** significant differences* (in which case *compare/contrast* is good), or you just want to ***identify something** as either an X or a Y* (in which case it's *distinguish/differentiate*).